# NIftyNet data organization

Tags: niftynet

I want to use NiftyNet to implement Deep Learning on medical image processing. However, there is one thing I haven't figured out regarding the data input: how does it join the multi-modality images? I saw the demo of BRATS2017, they seems to use 4 different modalities, and in the configuration file, they just included the directory of the images and they claim it will "concatenate" the images. But I want to know more, as those images are 3D, how are they concatenated? [slice1-30]:[slice1-30].. or [slice1, slice1, slice1 ...]:[slice2, slice2, slice2...]? 
And can we control the data organization part? If so, which file should I modify?

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the 3D images are concatenated in an additional dimension. You control the order they're concatenated in by specifying the order of files to load in the *.ini files.

However, as long as you're consistent, it shouldn't matter what order the modalities go in.

Answer (score 0):

The images are concatenated in the channel dimension. For 2D images, the dimensions are NSSC: batch size, 2 spatial dimensions, then channel. For 3D images, the dimensions are NSSSC: batch size, 3 spatial dimensions, then channel.